# VBA End If without block If for my predicament

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So I am getting an error: End If without block If, I am new to VBA and have tried to apply other threads answers to my own with no luck. Can you please help me. 
Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("B2:B6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        For Each KeyCells In Range(Target.Address)
        If KeyCells.Value <> "" Then KeyCells.Value = KeyCells.Value & "-CN"
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you have posted is syntactically fine and compiles without error. It is not however good code because it will result in an infinite loop - you need to disable events!

Comment: Agree with @Rory, but your code does produce an endless loop. I made a change in B2, and every time I click `OK`, it fires the worksheet change event when it enters `-CN` in the cell that was changed, firing this code again.

Comment: How can I change the For loop to only run once?

Comment: In Change Event code, whenever you change the value of the cell inside the code, the change event gets triggered again. To avoid this before the line where you change the cell content, disable the Events by using Application.EnableEvents = False and then after making the desired changes in the cell don't forget to enable the events again by using Application.EnableEvents = True.

Comment: Thanks sktneer!
!

Comment: @LasheenLartey You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

To ensure this fires only once you need to turn off `Events` inside the code, since the code itself makes a change to the cell, which again fires the exact event you are working with.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("B2:B6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) _
           Is Nothing Then 'since Target is range it will suffice here


        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

        Application.EnableEvents = False 'turn off events to avoid endless loop

        For Each KeyCells In Range(Target.Address)
            If KeyCells.Value <> "" Then  KeyCells.Value = KeyCells.Value & "-CN"
        Next

        Application.EnableEvents = True 'turn back on so events continue to fire

    End If

End Sub
```